# Android Studio + flutter won't open up

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[image: Project]

I open up this project and I am getting errors. I can't run the emulator without getting a lot of errors. I am new to Android Studio and Flutter.

Flutter Doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.11.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.11.0 at /Users/tobiadegoroye/flutter
    • Framework revision 856a90e67c (4 months ago), 2019-11-08 18:00:01 -0800
    • Engine revision af04338413
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tobiadegoroye/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.2.1, Build version 11B500
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods. For more info, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14293.
      To re-install CocoaPods, run:
        sudo gem install cocoapods

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: could you post your "flutter doctor -v"?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. If I run flutter doctor -v in the command line everything works fine, but if I choose Toos > Flutter > Flutter Doctor it says 'CocoaPods not installed'. So bash can find it but not Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Android Studio cannot locate the Flutter SDK because its path has changed. You can update the path of Flutter by configuring it to the installed Android Studio. On Windows, you can run `flutter config --android-studio-dir=${PATH_TO_ANDROID_STUDIO}` on the terminal as mentioned in this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#install-android-studio).